Why am I getting incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'Py_ssize_t' on an M1 mac?
Recently (April 2024), I started seeing the following error in a couple of builds on my M1 mac:
"error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]"

How do I fix it?

Downgrading xcode tools from 15.3 to 15.1 fixes the issue.

Uninstall by running sudo rm -rf /Library/Devloper/CommandLineTools source
Download old version https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools

